What is the minimum distance $d_\text{min}$ of a cyclic code with generator polynomial $g(x)=\prod_i \Phi_i(x)$ being cyclotomic?
Suppose I have a code $C=\langle g(x)\rangle \subseteq \mathbb{F}_q^n$ with $g(x)$ a product of cyclotomic polynomials of $x^n-1$. These codes do not necessarily satisfy the properties of a BCH code, so what bounds are known on their minimum distance? I have tried using the BCH bound on some examples and found consistencies, but I think this may be a pure coincidence.

Can you say something about the simpler case when $g(x)$ is just one cyclotomic polynomial instead of the product of two or more cyclotomic polynomials?

I am not sure. There are cyclotomic polynomials which have roots that are consecutive powers of some root of unity $\omega$, however most of them will not follow this structure. If we abandon this formalism however, and just look at an example like $C = \langle 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 \rangle$, then we can see that there is a codeword $1+x^5$ with weight 2, but IDK how to formalise this.

Well, for $C=\langle 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 \rangle$, $n$ must be a multiple of $5$, and so if $n>5$, the roots of $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ are not primitive $n$-th roots of unity. The number of consecutive $n$-th roots of unity that are roots of $g(x)$ is $1$, making the BCH bound $2$ which is equal to the actual minimum distance of the code.
